# iPhone app with CorePlot - archive issues

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, archive

I have developed an app using CorePlot. I've tested on emulator and also on a real device and runs fine. I've setup all those configurations in order to make work CorePlot in my app. But when I'm trying to archive the app I get this error:
**"CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file not found"**

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks.